# Need help identifying 75mm threaded sash window bolt

Tags: windows, bolts

I recently moved into a new flat with period wooden sash windows. Obviously they are not the most secure and any additional security we can add would be great. One of the sets of windows had 1 of these bolts in it but there are spaces for more, however I cannot seem to find any more of them to buy.

It is a 75mm long bolt with thread at one end with a square drive type (see attached picture). The threaded part is 25mm long, 7mm diameter and the thread size appears to be 1.42mm. The pin is 5mm diameter and 50mm long.

If anyone knows what the name for this particular type of bolt is I would be appreciative.

Many thanks.

[image: Picture of 75mm bolt]

Comment: An added picture showing how these are applied would be very helpful in identifying something that would work for you. Also try to specify the diameter of the pin (smooth part) and the size of the thread on the short threaded end. Determining thread could be as simple as taking the pictured pin to the hardware store and seeing what nut will fit on properly.